# popup in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-9

On the 'click' of a button, i open a new browser window. It works on Mozilla Firefox and IE9. But one of my PC having IE 9 installed. It does not work there. The new pop up window is forcible closed when it starts. I checked the pop-up blocker and all. I disabled the pop-up blocker. But no hope.

Comment: ....and how are you opening this new window? Without code, everyone would merely be guessing.

Comment: @Scott I open new window using JavaScript :)

Answer (score 0):

`Alt -> Interent Options -> choose Security tab -> mark trusted sites -> click sites -> click Add -> close.`

if you face any problem when you click add just uncheck th checkbox (Require server ...)